# Count the number of unique strings in a column in r with group by

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a data frame DF1 in this I have different type of furniture and there available colors, I need to consolidate it in a way as number of unique colors in which furniture are available. My result would be like DF2 as below.

```
Furniture_type=c("chair","chair","sofa","sofa","sofa","sofa","plate","sofa","plate","chair")
color=c("black","black","black","green","green","red","red","blue","blue","blue")
DF1=data.frame(Furniture_type,color)

Furniture_type1=c("chair","sofa","plate")
unique_color=c("black-2,blue-1","black-1,green-2,red-1,blue-1","red-1,blue-1")
DF2=data.frame(Furniture_type1,unique_color)
```

Can someone help me to solve this

Comment: Where is DF2? furniture_type 1 and 2 are same?

Comment: Hey sorry. typo error. I have updated the question now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```r
Furniture_type=c("chair","chair","sofa","sofa","sofa","sofa","plate","sofa","plate","chair")
color=c("black","black","black","green","green","red","red","blue","blue","blue")
DF1=data.frame(Furniture_type,color)

library(dplyr)

DF1 %>% group_by(Furniture_type, color) %>%
  summarise(n = n(), .groups = 'drop') %>%
  mutate(color = paste(color, n, sep = '-')) %>%
  group_by(Furniture_type) %>%
  summarise(unique_color = toString(color), .groups = 'drop')
#> # A tibble: 3 x 2
#>   Furniture_type unique_color                   
#>   <chr>          <chr>                          
#> 1 chair          black-2, blue-1                
#> 2 plate          blue-1, red-1                  
#> 3 sofa           black-1, blue-1, green-2, red-1
```

<sup>Created on 2021-05-24 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Answer (score 4):

You can use `count` and `summarise` :

```
library(dplyr)

DF1 %>%
  count(Furniture_type, color) %>%
  group_by(Furniture_type) %>%
  summarise(unique_color = paste(color, n, sep = '-', collapse = ','))

#  Furniture_type unique_color                
#  <chr>          <chr>                       
#1 chair          black-2,blue-1              
#2 plate          blue-1,red-1                
#3 sofa           black-1,blue-1,green-2,red-1
```

Answer (score 1):

An option with `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(DF1)[, .N, .(Furniture_type, color)[, 
          .(unique_color = toString(sprintf('%s-%s, color, n))), Furniture_type]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an other solution: We could use `add_count`, `unite`:

1. `group_by` `Furniture_type` and `color`
2. `add_count` to get the count
3. `unite` from `tidyr` package to combine `color` and `n`
4. `summarise` with `unique` and `collapse`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
DF1 %>% 
  group_by(Furniture_type, color) %>% 
  add_count %>% 
  unite("comb", c("color", "n"), sep = "-") %>% 
  summarise(unique_color = paste(as.character(unique(comb)), collapse = ","))
```

Output:

```
  Furniture_type unique_color                
  <chr>          <chr>                       
1 chair          black-2,blue-1              
2 plate          red-1,blue-1                
3 sofa           black-1,green-2,red-1,blue-1
```